# Angular Routing parent and children active

Tags: angular, routes

I have the scenario like when click on Parent menu item "technicalSettings", it is opening the empty view and child menu.

I'm looking for, when use clicks on parent menu item, view should not change. It should change only when clicks on child menu item.

**Angular**

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'technicalSettings',
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
          {
              path:'disciplines',
              component: DisciplinesComponent
          },
          {
              path:'disciplines/:disciplineId',
              component: DisciplinesComponent
          }
      ] },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ];
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="level-1" [ngClass]="openMenu ? 'expand-menu' : ''">

     <ul>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'Dashboard')"><i class="fa fa-dashboard " aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Dashboard</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'Data')"></i><span>Data</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="cis2-fa cis2-fa-mercedes" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'Vehicles')"></i><span>Vehicles</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'Favorites')"></i><span>Favorites</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'User Accounts')"></i><span>User Accounts</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  routerLink=""  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openSubMenu(true, false,'Technical Settings')"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true" ></i><span>Technical Settings</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'System Settings')"></i><span>System Settings</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openSubMenu(false, false, 'Projects')"></i><span>Projects</span><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="level-2" [ngClass]="openSubNav ? 'sub-menu' : ''">

    <ul *ngIf="vData">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  routerLink="/technicalSettings/disciplines" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openSubMenu(true, true, 'Disciplines')">Value Management <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openSubMenu(true, true, 'Parameters')">Excel Import <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openSubMenu(true, true, 'Technical')">Generate Documents<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue ? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm looking for, when use clicks on parent menu item, view should not change. It should change only when clicks on child menu item.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.